# grep lines in a text file displaying in firefox

Tags: firefox, grep, plugins

Like many others, I regularly look at test log files in a browser, it would be great to grep for lines containing a certain String.

Does anyone know a Firefox plugin that does this ?

Or ho I could place a grep function taking a variable parameter as a bookmarklet ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Vim addons on both Firefox and Chrome. It uses the same context as a Vim editor in Linux. You can press the <kbd>/</kbd> button and then the string you want.

This is not similar to the grep command though, it is more similar to the find feature, and honestly I haven't found an addon for grep. There is a [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)  though